Create URDF from DH parameter table and stl files
I want to create a URDF robot model of a KUKA KR150 R3300. I have the .stl files for each link, and i have the DH parameters table, where the DH parameter table represents the real robot measuring. Is there a way to create the URDF file using these data?
